# Business Working Hours based Due Date using joda

Tags: calendar, jodatime

Does Joda support methods to arrive at due date based on working hours

I was able to use 
- the holiday calendar 
- configurable working days 
to arrive at the due date

However, are there methods in joda to set the working hours as 8AM - 5PM and then calculate the due date ?

Sample scenario:
Time taken to complete a task: 10Hrs 
Business working hours: 8AM - 4PM (8 Hrs) 
Start Date of Task: 21-NOV-2016 ; 9AM 
Expected Due Date of Task: 22-NOV-2016 ; 11AM 
(i.e 7hrs of work completed on 21st 
 and 
3hrs of work completed on following working day which starts at 8AM)

Answer (score 1):

No. From the [Joda-Time documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time
>   classes.

It is not within scope to deal with working hours and scheduling.